# Elasticsearch Search/filter by occurrence or order in an array

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am having a **data** field in my index in which,

> I want only doc 2 as result i.e logically where **b** comes before
>   **a** in the array field data.

doc 1:

```
data = ['a','b','t','k','p']
```

doc 2:

```
data = ['p','b','i','o','a']
```

Currently, I am trying terms must on [a,b] then checking the order in another code snippet.
Please suggest any better way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the only way to do that would be to make use of [Span Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html), however it won't be applicable on an array of values.

You would need to concatenate the values into a single `text` field with `whitespace` as delimiter, reingest the documents and make use of [Span Near](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-near-query.html) query on that field:

Please find the below mapping, sample document, the query and response:

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_test_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "data":{
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST my_test_index/_doc/1
{
  "data": "a b"
}

POST my_test_index/_doc/2
{
  "data": "b a"
}
```

### Span Query:

```
POST my_test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "span_near" : {
            "clauses" : [
                { "span_term" : { "data" : "a" } },
                { "span_term" : { "data" : "b" } }
            ],
            "slop" : 0,                  <--- This means only `a b` would return but `a c b` won't. 
            "in_order" : true            <--- This means a should come first and the b
        }
    }
}
```

Note that **slop** `controls the maximum number of intervening unmatched positions permitted.`

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.36464313,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.36464313,
        "_source" : {
          "data" : "a b"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Yes it helps, I can change the slop parameter to achieve, my purpose thanks : )